# Continuity and Bernoulli's Equation in a vertical pipe with different cross sections

Tags: conservation-laws, flow, bernoulli-equation

Consider the following situation where the amount of water that goes through a cross section $A_1$ per second is the same as it goes through $A_0$ (just continuity) and **is always constant**:

[image]

I setup Bernoulli's equation to calculate the velocity ($v_1$) at $A_1$:
$$P_0+\rho g h_0+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2_0 = P_1+\rho g h_1+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2_1$$

Due to Pascal's law, the pressure ($P_1$) applied to $A_1$ has to continue and be applied to $A_0$ too, which makes $P_0 = P_1$. So we can cancel them out:
$$\rho g h_0+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2_0 =\rho g h_1+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2_1$$

Due to height ($h_0$) at $A_0$ being $0$, we can also simplify the equation further since $\rho g h_0 = 0$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2_0 =\rho g h_1+\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2_1$$

Since each term has $\rho$ we can divide them all by it to simplify further:

$$\frac{1}{2} v^2_0 =g h_1+\frac{1}{2} v^2_1$$

I now setup the continuity equation to isolate $v_0$ so that I can subtitue it in Bernoulli's equation and isolate $v_1$:

$$A_0v_0=A_1v_1 \\ \to v_0 = \frac{A_1v_1}{A_0}$$

I substitute the above $v_0$ in Bernoulli's equation that we simplified:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{A_1v_1}{A_0})^2 =g h_1+\frac{1}{2}v^2_1$$
Isolating $v_1$ gives:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\frac{A_1v_1}{A_0})^2 - \frac{1}{2}v^2_1=g h_1$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}v_1^2((\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2-1)=g h_1$$
$$\to v_1^2 = \frac{g h_1}{\frac{1}{2}((\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2-1)}$$
$$\to v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{2 g h_1}{ ((\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2-1)}}$$

## The problem

As you can see the $\frac{A_1}{A_0}$ part gives out a solution that's less than 1, since $A_1 < A_0$ (see the first picture). Following to this: $$\frac{A_1}{A_0} < 1 \to (\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2 < 1$$

This causes that I end up with a negative number under the square root since everything in the numerator is positive if we look them up: $$(\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2 - 1 < 0 \to \sqrt{\frac{+...}{(\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2-1}}$$

## What I tried:

I thought that maybe $g$ had to be negative since I was basically defining an axis and going down is negative. That basically cancels the negative in the denominator and we end up with an all positive term under the square root.

**However now with $g$ being negative in mind, I take the same situation and only make $A_0 < A_1$**:

[image]

Note that the only change here is $A_0$ and $A_1$, the heights still are the same. So deriving the formula again for $v_1$ like in the first situation should still output the same equation, but obviously we change g to be negative now so:

$$v_1 = \sqrt{\frac{- g *2* h_1}{ ((\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2-1)}}$$

But this time since $A_0 < A_1$ we do not end up with a negative number under the square root for the denominator, however my initial fix of making $g$ negative breaks this situation and I end up with a negative number in the numerator. So changing $g$ does not really help:

$$(\frac{A_1}{A_0})^2 - 1 > 0 \to \sqrt{\frac{-...}{+ ...}}$$

So it seems like if I take a situation like this and just replace the area's of the pipes without touching anything else (not even $g$) I can get a valid answer. But why doesn't it work the other way around?
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Just to be sure, the water is not free falling:

[image]

Comment: Your images are unreadable.

Comment: @BobD made them larger, all the green texts say "goes further".

Comment: Are you sure about your pascal’s law statement?

Comment: @Armadillo Wikipedia states: "a pressure change at any point in a confined incompressible fluid is transmitted throughout the fluid such that the same change occurs everywhere".

So, I think that it's right? Unless if Bernoulli's equation talks about water pressure coming from the opposite site (water itself that gets pushed creates pressure in opposite direction due to inertia?).

Comment: Is your fluid at rest or in motion? What situation is pascal’s law valid for?

Comment: @Armadillo I am trying to calculate the speed v_1 at A_1 so the fluid is in motion. I assumed that Pascal's law is always occurring in a continuous flow of water (if I push harder, the water throughout the whole pipe should speed up, right?).

Answer (score 1):

[Pascal’s law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law) cannot apply while the fluid is accelerating$^1$.

The mathematical statement of the law can be obtained from the Bernoulli’s equation above with $v_0=v_1$ so that $$\Delta p=\rho g\Delta h$$ and $\Delta p$ is *hydrostatic* pressure.

So the law itself in its derivation tells you that it holds only in cases where the fluid is stationary.

$^1$ Sure, a pressure to transmit through a fluid requires an acceleration/force, but the law applies when the force stops and the fluid reaches equilibrium.

Comment: But the amount of water that flows throughout a section is constant. Doesn't acceleration mean that the water would go faster and faster? Assume that every second 10 m^3 water is coming in and going out constantly.

Comment: Right. Which means Pascal’s law cannot hold during the flow, which is what you have assumed.

Comment: I understand that Pascal has to work in stationary situations. But then, if I still use it, but add a absolute || function at my denominator. My results come out correct. So, ... is it a coincidence? I have used the same logic in multiple questions and it just works. I just don't know how to justify the absolute function.

Comment: I doubt it’s coincidence, but nevertheless you don’t apply the law directly to moving fluids. Let me have a think about that and I’ll get back. Cheers.

Comment: After thinking about Pascal's law being applied to hydraulics. We use big position change and tiny force to move big forces (weights) through tiny position change. So at its base Pascal's law should still work with different speeds of flows. Just imagine the flow being the push force through a tiny pipe that pushes a part of the pipe that's huge (a lot more weight).

Comment: Sure, but Pascal's Law is _not_ valid for hydraulics while the actual _lifting_ (or whatever) takes place since in that case acceleration occurs. However, you’re correct _only_ if we consider the initial and final states. That’s why hydraulic equipment also have smaller “release tubes” for the additional force generated _during_ the pressure change.

Comment: If I take some fluid and let it free fall. Every particle will accelerate or have the same speed at any given time right? So from the perspective of the water, it is the world that's accelerating towards the water. So basically the pressure (water particles being close to each other), shouldn't change right? So, ... doesn't that mean that I can just measure the pressure from the water's perspective and use Pascal while the water is accelerating?

Comment: Nvm, then v_0 = v_1, you're right.

Comment: Glad you’ve got it. Good luck with your studies. Cheers

Comment: I mean I know my error, but I still don't know why my answer works if there's no negatives or when I use an absolute function.

Comment: Good. I’ll get back to you on the math part as soon as I have some time. Cheers